# Download published accdb (Access Database)

Tags: microsoft-access

How can you download a database published from MS Access 2010 to Sharepoint 2010? (accdb not the old mdb format). I need to do this inside a python script with no user interaction. 
There does not seem to be a solution to directly access the database through Sharepoint, so I guess the only option left is to read the database locally after downloading it.

[EDIT] The image shows the difference between normal lists (Test) and accdb files (A_Test) 
[image: sp accdb]

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?  Once a database is 'published' to SharePoint via Access Services, it creates lists in SharePoint that represent the various tables.  There should be no need to work with the database directly, at least for data purposes.

Comment: Sure. If I create a simple table that can be stored as mdb, you are right. But accdb consist of several tables. Published, the accdb is not a list (i.e when calling GetListCollection it is not enumerated), but as a site (which can be accessed through sp-site.com/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx). So the new Access format does not seem to be accessible through the Lists api, nor do I see methods to get to the actual table's content in the Web api.

Comment: According to the picture, there are several lists below A_Test, which is the published accdb. To see these I needed to connect to the url directly above those lists, which in this case is: sp.site.com/personal/USERNAME/A_Test_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL So it is possible to access the database through Lists api. It is just, that a new site is created to act as container for several tables. And you need to connect to this subsite to access the tables.

Comment: If this is a solution to your issue, I'll reword my comment as an answer so it can be flagged for future reference

Comment: Hi Dave. Better yet, could you post your answer in the following thread? I will accept your answer and link to it here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77652/get-data-from-published-accdb-access-database

Comment: should be all set.  Glad you were able to get to the answer