# Querying Published Access 2010 Web Database from SQL Server

Tags: 2010, sql-server, microsoft-access

I have a published Access 2010 Web Database on my SharePoint 2010 site. The forms and tables all work as expected, but I would like to query this database from SQL Server. Is this possible?

Essentially I have a ticketing system set up in SharePoint via this Access Web Database, and another tool that stores its data in SQL Server. I want to use data from the ticketing system in queries for that tool.

I've seen answers to questions wanting to go the other way (link SQL Server tables in an Access Web Database), and understand that's not really possible, but I'd like to access the data in the Web Database from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because publishing an Access 2010 Web Database to SharePoint results in the tables being turned into SharePoint lists, I ended up using SharePoint list adapters for SQL Sever Integration Services: http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

This allowed me to import the list data to SQL Server on a regular basis, where I could run all the queries I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand, you want to access the Access Web Database from the SQL server to run queries?

Here is post which explain how to get data from access published database, once you get the data using the web service then you need to write another logic to insert the data into SQL server. Check here

[Get Data from Published accdb (Access) Database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77652/get-data-from-published-accdb-access-database?rq=1)

another good link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583943/query-access-database-from-sql-management-studio-without-using-linked-servers